# NSXmlParser parse XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I try to parse this Xml

```
<Options>
<Option ModeHTMorTXT="HTM"/>
<Option last_NEW_Signature="COB_DE_m.buettner_Extern"/>
<Option last_FR_Signature="COB_DE_m.buettner_Extern"/>
<Option FileList="COB_DE_m.buettner_Confidential.htm"/>
<Option FileList="COB_DE_m.buettner_Extern.htm"/>
<Option FileList="COB_DE_m.buettner_intern.htm"/>
</Options>
```

anybody can write how to parse this XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to set up GDataXML. This parser it's easy to set up and easy to use.
For further info I suggest you to read about [how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml).

If you use ARC you need to set the classes provided by GDataXML with the compiler configuration -fno-objcarc. You can find info searching on the web.

Hope it helps.